# Need to design something like Gmail's Inbox page

Tags: user-interface, gmail, playframework

I want to make a user interface like Gmail's inbox page in my web application (the focus is on the way it lists the messages and shows them), but have no idea of how it's been designed.

I've never designed a professional web UI before, so I would be glad if you guide me to the simplest way.

(My application is written in Java and I'm using play framework by the way)

Answer (score 6):

If you would like something as snappy and rich looking as gmail, then more than likely you are going to have to feel comfortable using some sort of Javascript and CSS combination.

It looks like the gmail app makes heavy use of AJAX, so be prepared to understand and at least learn the basics of this technology.

I would say grab a good book or do some more research on one or more of the following technologies:

- Javascript (perhaps the JQuery framework)
- CSS3
- AJAX
- HTML 5
- JSON

If you haven't really worked on a web UI before, I would also suggest lowering your standards a bit first.  To create something as rich and functional as gmail would be a daunting task for a newbie web developer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like gmail and don't want to mess with html, javascript, ajax... I think the easiest and fastest way is that you take a look at GWT: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

It's a tool to design your front-end directly in java and it compiles into javascript with all the hacks for browser compatibilities.

There's a play module to integrate gwt in your application: http://www.playframework.org/modules/gwt

Comment: For these kinds of rich clients you can also have a look at vaadin https://vaadin.com, it's built on top of GWT

Comment: The only snag you may run into when using widget-based frameworks like GWT or the excellent Vaadin is that they are inherently and unequivocally stateful. This is something that Play! tries to avoid at all costs, so there's a a very fundamental philosophy gap there. In fact, I'm not sure if anyone has ever tried to integrate Vaadin with Play! - and I don't really see an easy way to do it either (I may be wrong, naturally).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/).

One of the tutorials specifically builds a GMail style application, and I know that a few Play apps have already been built using Knockout on the front end.

I believe there are tutorials and blogs by Felipe Oliveira on using Knockout with Play if you need more support.

Comment: Ironically, perhaps, that page fails to display in my Firefox 8 (Linux, x86_64). I get a sea of JavaScript source code smeared across an orange background … :-(

Comment: Just for your information: Knockout is very interesting and useful, but will only really help you *structure* your client-side JS objects. It doesn't provide widgets or UI elements at all.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to basic design, I think you'll be looking at using Play! almost exclusively as a (possibly [RESTful](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/)) *service provider* for your JavaScript-based client-side interface code. By this I mean that most of your controllers will in fact be rendering JSON (or some other format, whatever you prefer) to feed your client-side UI components. This is great though, as the routing configuration used in Play! fits this pattern perfectly.

To build the actual UI, you might want to look at JavaScript UI frameworks such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) or [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/). You'll have to build your UI using the JavaScript framework and have the components call your Play! framework controller actions to read, create and update data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not designed in java, its in php but atleast you will get idea.
http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/gmail-look-and-feel-html5-history-api-hashbang